# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in xampp 3.2.2 and php v7.2

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, driver

Here is my code:

```
$servername = "GOUTAM";
$conninfo= array("database"=>"matrimony","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"root");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $servername,$conninfo );

if($conn)
    echo "Connection Successful";

else
{
    echo "<br>Failed....";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
```

I downloaded ODBC 13 driver and SQLserver driver 40, and I also successfully added .dll files in php.ini.

It is still giving me an error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please include a paste of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download version 5.3 (or 5.2) of PHP Driver for SQL Server if you use PHP 7.2. Check the [support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

After download, do the following things:

- download and install appropriate [ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) - version 17+ (or 13.1)
- put the appropriate dll files in PHP extensions directory
- run `<?php phpinfo();?>` to check if "sqlsrv" section exists